# How to create an "irregular" month gantt chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm playing with line chart graphs to create a gantt diagram.
I managed obtain an axis displaying all months by using:

- Bounds: min - max month timestamp. Ex between 02 of may and 05 of november
- Units: major: 30 (number of days in a month), minor: 5 (number of days in a week)
- Number: custom category, with format "mmm"

My problem is that on the month of May I have more activities and I'd like more space to give more insight, on the contrary in August it is fine to have less space. 
Is it possible to create a "variable" axis?

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1442150/edit) to provide the current chart and show us what the expected output is? Sample data may also be useful.

Comment: Could provide sample source about your problem?